# Jest unit tests failing with MsalModule does not have a module def (ɵmod property)

Tags: angular, jestjs, msal-angular

I suspect this might be related to Ivy and
@azure/msal-angular [es2015/esm2015] being compiled with target.
I have been trying to run jest unit tests on a project that imports MsalModule and I am getting that error.

Comment: Any resolution on this?

Answer (score 0):

I am now using jest-preset-angular with esm defaults.
https://thymikee.github.io/jest-preset-angular/docs/guides/esm-support